# Back End Table Constantly Locks up completely

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I'm having trouble with a DB I created for tracking support tickets at work and I can NOT figure out what the issue is - Really hoping some one here may be able to figure it out?

The issue is that when I provide the file to people, each having their own saved version of the Front End - The back end Table eventually starts locking up completely causing errors for EVERYONE and I can't determine why.

**Creation:**
I created a Back End table to hold the records that will be ADDED - Tbl_Tickets.
I created an additional file that contains some information that is pulled and added to the tbl_tickets, regarding the person logging the ticket, date, time and a few others.
Both these back end tables were linked back to the Front End file I created. Frm_TicketEntry.

This form has been set to "No Locking" - as from what I have read, this only locks the file when writing changes.

I have a Button to add a new record. This Creates a new entry in Tbl_Tickets, sets so default values for required fields, and saves the ticket, then returns to the previous ticket to continue with editing / entering information.
I also have a "Save Record" button - This saves the newly edited information on the form and then refreshes all - This updates the SubForm / Report that shows the previous 5 tickets in the table.

Now, from "Debugging" when the errors pop up I can see the issue is generally when attempting to run the save record command - DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord - either as part of the "new record" Sub or "Save" Sub. Though when checking the back end I can see its because it has been completely locked.

I can provide all my code - But providing the files themselves will be an issue - Due to works regulations on providing work related files etc :/

I'm at the end of my run with this and if unable to resolve these issue - I will have to relinquish this project to some one else.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, somehow your code or an object does lock the table even if you don't think so.

You can try to replace your saving code using the method and code here:

[Handle concurrent update conflicts in Access silently](https://rdsrc.us/q4riET)

Alternatively here:

[Full URL](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/25780/Handle-concurrent-update-conflicts-in-Access-silently.html?sharedLinkId=7P1lSqPS7NY%3D&cid=2035&cid=2035)

It will not solve all possible conflict scenarios, but at least it could indicate where or when something doesn't behave as intended.

Code at GitHub: [VBA.ConcurrencyUpdates](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ConcurrencyUpdates.git)

Comment: Don't mean to be a pain in the ass - But I can't seem to load the link :/ - do you perchance have the complete URL?